# NGinx not routing between Node.js back-end and React front-end

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a deployed a web app wih a Node.js back-end and React front-end on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the NGINX default configuration.

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 4;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
}
```

My back-end runs on port 8081 (with Express.js) and doesn't receive any of the calls made by the front-end i.e. `fetch("http:127.0.0.1/api/volatility")`.

In the console I see `GET https://foo-bar.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com:8080/api/volatility net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

Any way to this fix this?

Comment: try     `server nodejs:8081;` (instead of `127.0.0.1` in upstream config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Elastic Beanstalk service didn't have permission to read/write in the database.